# Invoke abstract class method using reflection c#

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection

My external dll design looks like :

```
class Engineering
{
   ProjectsCollection project {get;}
}

abstract class ProjectsCollection
{
   public abstract Project Open(string path);
}
```

I'm able to proceed till getting the method info

```
MethodInfo info = type.GetMethod("Open");
```

How to invoke the method "Open"?

Comment: [MethodInfo.Invoke Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Using which class are you trying to invoke the method ? You want an instance of a type that provides an implementation for the method Open. Abstract method has no implementation in `ProjectsCollection`. Do you have a class inheriting from `ProjectsCollection`? If yes, then show it. If no, then you can't invoke that method.

Comment: Read a bit further what you´ve already read to learn about `GetMethod`. I bet the same ressource has a chapter about invoking the received member. As an aside: it makes no difference, if your method is abtsract or not, as you need an actual *instance* of the type. As you can´t create an instance of an abstract class, you have to create one of a sub-class and invoke the method on this instance.

Comment: Why is this method tagged C# and Java? `Dynamic` btw. is quite meaningless I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection or not, you cannot invoke an abstract method, because there is nothing to invoke. Sure, you can write

```
info.Invoke(eng.project, new object[] {path});
```

but it will throw an exception unless `eng.project` is set to an object of a non-abstract class descendent from `ProjectCollection`, which implements the `Open` method:

```
class ProjectsCollectionImpl : ProjectsCollection {
    public Project Open(string path) {
        return ...
    }
}

Engineering eng = new Engineering(new ProjectsCollectionImpl());
MethodInfo info = type.GetMethod("Open");
var proj = info.Invoke(eng.project, new object[] {path});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `Invoke`!

```
info.Invoke(someObject, new object[] {"This is the parameter of the method"});
```

Simple as that!

The return value of `Invoke` will be the return value of `Open`, which should be a `Project` object.

From the docs:

> Invokes the method or constructor represented by the current instance, using the specified parameters.

Oh, and you should know that `someObject` above is the object that you're calling the method on. You should always make it an instance of a concrete class! Don't give it `null`!

Comment: It can be *NULL* if we're invoking a static method.

Comment: @user3185569 The `Open` method here is obviously not static.

Comment: You used the always word which can be understood as something that should never be done in other way.